# Check if an object exists within an array

Tags: javascript

I have the following array, `myArray` and object, `myObject`. Is there a way I can determine if `myObject` exists within `myArray`?

```
const myArray = [ { id: 1, lastName: "Garland", firstName: "Darius", email: "test@example.com" },
                  { id: 2, lastName: "Sexton", firstName: "Collin", email: "fake@example.com"  } ]

const myObject = { lastName: "Sexton", email: "fake@example.com" }
```

Comment: tthis can't never be, they are two object with 2 differents memory address

Comment: `myArray.includes(myObject)`. Objects are compared by reference though, given the code you show it will always be `false`. Also, none of the objects in the array is contained in the array even if JS were to compare by objects contents. I suggest you reword your question *check if array holds an object where all object properties of myObject are defined and hold the same values as myObject does*.

Comment: @noclist In your example, do you consider `myObject` exist in `myArray`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `some` with `every` to get the desired output.

```js
const myArray = [ { id: 1, lastName: "Garland", firstName: "Darius", email: "test@example.com" }, { id: 2, lastName: "Sexton", firstName: "Collin", email: "fake@example.com"  } ];

const myObject = { lastName: "Sexton", email: "fake@example.com" };

const result = myArray.some(k=>Object.entries(myObject).every(([key,v])=>k[key]===v));

const result2 = myArray.some(k=>Object.entries(k).every(([key,v])=>myObject[key]===v));

console.log(result);
console.log(result2);
```

Comment: wouldn't having a generic function have been a better idea?

Comment: Now what if `myObject` has properties that the "corresponding" object in the array does not have?

Comment: @connexo It doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

same as **gorak** but done with explicit generics functions

```js
const objPartsExistInArr = (obj,arr) => arr.some(o=>Object.entries(obj).every(([k,v])=>o[k]===v))
const fullObjExistInArr  = (obj,arr) => arr.some(o=>Object.entries(o).every(([k,v])=>obj[k]===v))

const myArray = 
  [ { id: 1, lastName: 'Garland', firstName: 'Darius', email: 'test@example.com' } 
  , { id: 2, lastName: 'Sexton',  firstName: 'Collin', email: 'fake@example.com' } 
  ] 
const myObjP = { lastName: 'Sexton', email: 'fake@example.com' } 
const myObjF = { id: 2, lastName: 'Sexton', firstName: 'Collin', email: 'fake@example.com' } 

console.log('objPartsExistInArr ->', objPartsExistInArr( myObjP, myArray ) )
console.log('fullObjExistInArr  ->', fullObjExistInArr( myObjF, myArray ) )
```

Answer (score -2):

Use the "indexOf" method of the array! This returns "-1" if if the desired element is not found.
You can also use the "includes" method of the array like this:

```js
var nums=[1, 2]
console.log(nums.includes(1));//returns true
```

Comment: Objects are compared by reference, not by value. So your answer would only be valid if OP was asking for exactly that - which we cannot know because their question lacks crucial information about when they expect true and false.